# Add product to cart using jquery ajax not working

Tags: php, jquery, magento, cart

I am using ajax to add product in cart using code:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$cart->addProduct($product,array('qty'=>1));
$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

When I click on add to cart this adds the product(lets say CPU) successfully, then I add any other product (lets say Laptop) then it fails to add the Laptop product in cart but when i add the Laptop product second time then it is added to cart successfully. I am not able to locate the problem. Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what parameters are pass in ajax call ? have you check your ajax call in console ?

Comment: yes I have checked it, I have passed product id from there and it's value is right in console

Comment: Do you have a live demo to help with debugging?

Comment: okai. print the value of variable "$product" before "addProduct" line for confermation of correct values.

Code Example:
var_dump($product);
$cart->addProduct($product,array('qty'=>1));

Comment: it is displaying object type

Answer (score 1):

In magento the add to cart process is a simple form submit process, so the page get reloaded.Therefore, Ajax based Shopping Cart comes as a solution to fasten the buying process. Step by step process: [How to Add Product To Cart Using Ajax](http://blog.abacasys.com/2016/11/10/add-product-cart-using-ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Just do onething call product add to cart link on button with url attribute like..

```
> <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('add to cart') ?>"
> class="button btn-cart addsample" url ="<?php echo
> $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>"><span><span><?php echo
> $this->__('add to cart') ?></span></span></button></div>
```

Now use this ajax post.

```
$j('button.addsample').click(function(){
            $j(this).attr('disabled','disabled');

            $j.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            cache   : false,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            url: $j(this).attr('url'),
                            data: data,
                            success:function(data){

                                setTimeout(function() {
                                            window.location.reload();
                                    }, 1600);   


                                },
                            error:function(){

                                    setTimeout(function() {
                                            window.location.reload();
                                    }, 1600);   

                        }


            });

    });
```

Here i am sending ajax post to magento's default add to cart controller.. hope this will be helpful to you

Comment: i cannot use this method as i am not using catalog/product page for 'add to cart' button's location actually i have done some customization and i am displaying product on a different page so $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product)  responds with empty values.

Comment: Can you show me your custom code to get product collection